# Using ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When using ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION in a batch script, do the variables that are created within it still exist after calling ENDLOCAL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand, your question is basically about the `SETLOCAL` command and its effects, regardless of the `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` option (or any other one) used.

My short answer is: **No**, assuming the variables didn't exist prior to entering `SETLOCAL`'s scope.

My longer answer is as follows:

All the changes made to a variable within the scope of `SETLOCAL` are discarded upon exiting the scope (i.e. upon reaching `ENDLOCAL`). This includes:

- defining a previously undefined variable:

  ```
  @ECHO OFF

  <nul SET /P q=1.
  IF DEFINED ttt (ECHO defined) ELSE (ECHO undefined)

  SETLOCAL

  SET ttt=
  <nul SET /P q=2.
  IF DEFINED ttt (ECHO defined) ELSE (ECHO undefined)

  ENDLOCAL

  <nul SET /P q=3.
  IF DEFINED ttt (ECHO defined) ELSE (ECHO undefined)
  ```

  This outputs:

  ```
  1.undefined
  2.defined
  3.undefined
  ```
- undefining a previously defined variable:

  ```
  @ECHO OFF

  SET ttt=1
  <nul SET /P q=1.
  IF DEFINED ttt (ECHO defined) ELSE (ECHO undefined)

  SETLOCAL

  SET ttt=
  <nul SET /P q=2.
  IF DEFINED ttt (ECHO defined) ELSE (ECHO undefined)

  ENDLOCAL

  <nul SET /P q=3.
  IF DEFINED ttt (ECHO defined) ELSE (ECHO undefined)
  ```

  The output is:

  ```
  1.defined
  2.undefined
  3.defined
  ```
- changing a variable's value:

  ```
  @ECHO OFF

  SET ttt=1
  ECHO 1.ttt=%ttt%

  SETLOCAL

  SET ttt=2
  ECHO 2.ttt=%ttt%

  ENDLOCAL

  ECHO 3.ttt=%ttt%
  ```

  And this produces the following output:

  ```
  1.ttt=1
  2.ttt=2
  3.ttt=1
  ```

As I said in the beginning, the above applies to `SETLOCAL` regardless of whether you use it with additional options or not.

In conclusion I'd like to say that it is possible to save the result calculated within `SETLOCAL`'s scope, for use after `ENDLOCAL`. Here's a little trick that makes it possible:

```
…
ENDLOCAL & SET var=%var%
…
```

At the time of *parsing* this line, the `SETLOCAL` command is still in effect, so `%var%` gets evaluated to the value you've stored into `var` most lately. When the line is *executed*, the `var` variable loses its value immediately after `ENDLOCAL`, but the SET command already contains its value, just substituted, so `var` receives it back, to everybody's satisfaction.

As per @Jeremy Murray's comment, you could also get access to the changed value after `ENDLOCAL` if you included `ENDLOCAL` and the command(s) reading the variable in a single block enclosed in parentheses:

```
…
(
ENDLOCAL
SET var=%var%
anything else
)
…
```

The effect would be the same because bracketed commands are both parsed and executed as a single unit: first they are *all* parsed, *then* they are all executed.

Comment: You can also put endlocal inside a paren statement to do multiple sets, if needed. [imagine the newlines in this example, please :)]    ( ENDLOCAL
    IF NOT "%RETURN_SIG%" == "" SET "SIGNATURE=%RETURN_SIG%"
    IF "%RETURN_SIG%" == "" SET "SIGNATURE=%DEFAULT_SIG%"
)

Comment: @Jeremy Murray: Absolutely. All bracketed commands are parsed before the first one of them executes. So it's the same effect as if they were on the same line. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I take it enabledelayedexpansion can only be used if SETLOCAL is called?

Comment: @Mechaflash: That's what I'm told, yes.

Comment: But to preserve **any** possible content after an endlocal, it's much more complicated, as something like `you & me said "me & you"` would fail with the `set var=%var%` variant

Comment: @jeb: Agree. There should be a separate answer dedicated to covering all possible cases, and, consequently, there should be a separate question too. :)